# Preparing for Swift 3: Is there a clean way to refactor this "classic" do…while statement?

Tags: objective-c, c, swift, refactoring, do-while

I'm trying to refactor a small amount of legacy non-functional-totally-procedural-old-school-"is this FORTRAN?!" code, and I'd like some input.

Since Swift 3 is getting rid of the "confusing" `++` prefix/postfix operator, along with C-style `for` loops, I've been hard at work updating my gross Swift 2.0 *(and really gross C and Objective-C)* files, and for the most part, it hasn't been too bad. However, I've run into one of those pesky `do...while` loops that I probably wrote after a night of heavy drinking.

Here's a slimmed down version of the original code:

```objc
BSDPath *startPath = &ctx->paths[startIdx];
BSDPath *endPath = &ctx->paths[endIdx];
BSDPath *currentPath = startPath;

do {
    if (flags & CurveElement) {
        // ... Some code here ...
    }
} while (currentPath++ != endPath);
```

I've Swiftified some stuff, and now I'm here:

```swift
let startPath = ctx.paths[index]
let endPath = ctx.paths[endIndex]
var currentPath = startPath

repeat {
    if flags.contains(.Curve) {
        // ... Some code here ...
    }
    index += 1
    currentPath = ctx.paths[index]
} while currentPath != endPath
```

As you can C, I've Swiftly converted most of it to the new nice and clean Apple of my eye. However, I can't help but wonder if there's an even cleaner way of writing this — that is, without totally throwing out the bath water and giving in to the `for...in` siren song. To be honest, I'm not even sure if that code runs correctly. I've never really been able to wrap my head around the control flow of the `do...while` statement. I mean, I get how it works, but it just seems backwards to me. But I digress.

I suppose the reason I want to know the "cleanest" way to rewrite my old stuff is that I just kind of miss being able wrap assignment statements in parentheses to kill two bytes with one var. I totally agree that the `++` operator is counterintuitive, but for all it's jankiness, it certainly did take a little of the tedium out of typing into a code editor all day. But I digress (again?!).

Anyway, that's all I've got. I would love to know of any timesavers I'm unaware of, but any thoughts, ideas, or comments are welcome and greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What you've written isn't right — the code to update `index` and `currentPath` shouldn't be inside the `if`.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't simply do `for currentPath in ctx.paths`?

Comment: `while (currentPath++ != endPath)` ... I'm so glad that's no longer in Swift...

Comment: If you're prepared to post the *actual* implementation, you can get your code reviewed at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @jtbandes You're right. Thanks for the heads-up. I've updated the post. Regarding your question about why I don't just use a `for` loop: I don't really have a particular reason. I totally can, and that's probably what I'll wind up doing. I was just wondering if there's a more 1-to-1 equivalent I should be using. Like… when you're reading documentation, and you see that a method is deprecated. Below that, it usually says "Use `x` instead." That's all I really wanted to know. My post is just kind of all over the place. That's just my ADD. :-) Thanks for the reply though. I appreciate it.

Comment: Rather than a 1-to-1 equivalent, I think you should (always) be in search of the cleanest solution!

Comment: @nhgrif I just might do that! Thanks for the link! And yeah, like I said, I don't want `++` to come back, but I wouldn't mind being able to initialize variables with the old `var a = b = 0`. It seems more efficient to me than separately initializing variables when they're all going to be set to the same value. Just like the increment operator, though, I can understand why it's not built in to the language. Oh well… I think I'm just being whiny today. Thanks for replying though, and I'll definitely check out Code Review. Gracias.

Comment: @jtbandes Touché! Very good point.